# Mysql data manipulation query not return results?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created this query to get data from multiple tables,

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_acc;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_loan;

CREATE 
TEMPORARY TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS 
tmp_acc AS 
    (SELECT
        ac.date,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(cash) FROM accounts WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), 0)AS op_cash,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(bank) FROM accounts WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)),0)AS op_bank,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(ho_funds) FROM accounts WHERE date = ac.date), 0)AS ho_funds,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(recieved) FROM funds WHERE date = ac.date AND branch_to = 'kandy' AND method = 'Cash'),0)AS funds_cash,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(recieved) FROM funds WHERE date = ac.date AND branch_to = 'kandy' AND method = 'Bank'),0)AS funds_bank,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(diposit) FROM bank WHERE date = ac.date),0)AS diposits,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(withdraw) FROM bank WHERE date = ac.date ),0)AS withdrawals
    FROM accounts ac);

CREATE 
TEMPORARY TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS 
tmp_loan AS 
    SELECT ls.date, COUNT(l.idloan)AS count, l.interest,l.admission_fee,l.document_fee,l.insuarance,
        (SELECT SUM(d1.overdue) FROM daily_collections d1 WHERE d1.loan_idloan = l.idloan)AS overdue_collection,
        ls.completed_date
    FROM loan l 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN daily_collections d ON l.idloan = d.loan_idloan 
    JOIN loan_session ls ON ls.loan_idloan = l.idloan
    WHERE ls.completed = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY  ls.completed_date,l.interest;

    SELECT
        a.date,COALESCE(a.op_cash,0)AS op_cash,COALESCE(a.op_bank,0)AS op_bank, COALESCE(a.ho_funds,0)AS ho_funds,
        COALESCE(a.funds_cash,0)AS funds_cash, COALESCE(a.funds_bank,0)AS funds_bank,COALESCE( a.diposits,0)AS diposits, COALESCE(a.withdrawals,0)AS withdrawals,
        COALESCE(l.count,0)AS count, COALESCE(l.interest,0)AS interest, COALESCE(l.admission_fee,0)AS admision_fee,
        COALESCE(l.document_fee,0)AS document_fee, COALESCE(l.insuarance,0)AS insrance, COALESCE(l.overdue_collection,0)AS overdue_collection
    FROM tmp_acc a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp_loan l ON a.date = l.completed_date
    WHERE MONTH(a.date) = MONTH(current_date())
```

I used this query to generate Jasper report and to view data in java. This query working fine in workbench, and it returns all results.

But it's not working in java. I used `Statement.executeQuery()` and assign to `ResultSet`. I printed `ResultSet`, but nothing is printing.

How can I execute this query in java?

Java code

```java
public ArrayList<cashObject> getCashbookData(String date) {
        ArrayList<cashObject> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            conn c = new conn();
            String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_acc;\n"
                    + "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_loan;\n"
                    + "                \n"
                    + " CREATE \n"
                    + "    TEMPORARY TABLE \n"
                    + "    IF NOT EXISTS \n"
                    + "                tmp_acc AS \n"
                    + "                (SELECT\n"
                    + "                ac.date,\n"
                    + "             COALESCE((SELECT SUM(cash) FROM accounts WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), 0)AS op_cash,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(bank) FROM accounts WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(ac.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)),0)AS op_bank,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(ho_funds) FROM accounts WHERE date = ac.date), 0)AS ho_funds,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(recieved) FROM funds WHERE date = ac.date AND branch_to = 'kandy' AND method = 'Cash'),0)AS funds_cash,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(recieved) FROM funds WHERE date = ac.date AND branch_to = 'kandy' AND method = 'Bank'),0)AS funds_bank,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(diposit) FROM bank WHERE date = ac.date),0)AS diposits,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(withdraw) FROM bank WHERE date = ac.date ),0)AS withdrawals\n"
                    + "                FROM accounts ac);\n"
                    + "                \n"
                    + "                CREATE \n"
                    + "                TEMPORARY TABLE \n"
                    + "                IF NOT EXISTS \n"
                    + "                tmp_loan AS \n"
                    + "                SELECT ls.date, COUNT(l.idloan)AS count, l.interest,l.admission_fee,l.document_fee,l.insuarance,\n"
                    + "                \n"
                    + "                (SELECT SUM(d1.overdue) FROM daily_collections d1 WHERE d1.loan_idloan = l.idloan)AS overdue_collection,\n"
                    + "                ls.completed_date\n"
                    + "                FROM loan l \n"
                    + "                LEFT OUTER JOIN daily_collections d ON l.idloan = d.loan_idloan \n"
                    + "                JOIN loan_session ls ON ls.loan_idloan = l.idloan\n"
                    + "                WHERE ls.completed = 'Yes'\n"
                    + "                GROUP BY  ls.completed_date,l.interest;\n"
                    + "                \n"
                    + "                SELECT\n"
                    + "                a.date,COALESCE(a.op_cash,0)AS op_cash,COALESCE(a.op_bank,0)AS op_bank, COALESCE(a.ho_funds,0)AS ho_funds,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE(a.funds_cash,0)AS funds_cash, COALESCE(a.funds_bank,0)AS funds_bank,COALESCE( a.diposits,0)AS diposits, COALESCE(a.withdrawals,0)AS withdrawals,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE(l.count,0)AS count, COALESCE(l.interest,0)AS interest, COALESCE(l.admission_fee,0)AS admision_fee,\n"
                    + "                COALESCE(l.document_fee,0)AS document_fee, COALESCE(l.insuarance,0)AS insrance, COALESCE(l.overdue_collection,0)AS overdue_collection\n"
                    + "                FROM tmp_acc a \n"
                    + "                LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp_loan l ON a.date = l.completed_date\n"
                    + "                WHERE MONTH(a.date) = '" + date + "' ";

            Statement st = c.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery(query);

            System.out.println("RS :: " + rs);

            while (rs.next()) {

                cashObject o = new cashObject();
                o.setDate(rs.getString(0));
                o.setOp_cash(parseDouble(rs.getString(1)));
                o.setOp_bank(parseDouble(rs.getString(2)));
                o.setHo_funds(parseDouble(rs.getString(3)));
                o.setFunds_cash(parseDouble(rs.getString(4)));
                o.setFunds_bank(parseDouble(rs.getString(5)));
                o.setDiposits(parseDouble(rs.getString(6)));
                o.setWithdrawals(parseDouble(rs.getString(7)));
                o.setCount(parseInt(rs.getString(8)));
                o.setInterest(parseDouble(rs.getString(9)));
                o.setAdmission_fee(parseDouble(rs.getString(10)));
                o.setDocument_fee(parseDouble(rs.getString(11)));
                o.setInsuarance(parseDouble(rs.getString(12)));
                o.setOverdueCollection(parseDouble(rs.getString(13)));
                results.add(o);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        // print size of arraylist
        System.out.println("CLASS : " + results.size());
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Since we don't have the Java code that you claim isn't working, who knows? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Thank you @jdv, I added java code

Comment: Are you really using JasperReports? What is a reason of using `Statement.executeQuery()` if you are using JR?

Comment: @AlexK : I'm using jasper report to generate report.but before i need to show this results in jTable. Thats why i used `Statement.executeQuery()` to execute query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default configuration, you can't execute multiple statements like that, because a statement is intended to execute a single statement, not a script.

You need to execute the five statements in your script separately, so

```
statement.execute("drop table ...");
statement.execute("drop table ...");
statement.execute("create temporary table ...");
statement.execute("create temporary table ...");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select ...");
```

Alternatively, you could try to use the MySQL specific connection property `allowMultiQueries=true`; this will allow you to execute multiple statements. Its behavior is technically not allowed by the JDBC standard, and I don't know if it will work or not for this specific example.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Rotterveel. I'll try that.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark Rotteveel. This is working fine